# Python : print a traceback afterwards

Tags: python, traceback

I have a script running 24/7 on my Pi.
Something went wrong in a *Try: except:* block in which I failed to include a traceback object (https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html), so I don't really know what went wrong in my function.

The script is still running (in screen). Is there a way I can print a traceback now?

Comment: Please share your code with us

Comment: @Arman: that's hardly going to help here.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Agreed. Nevertheless, 5 people voted against my question.

Comment: Not the very best question, but not so bad so I wonder why it deserves so many downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. Update your code to also log the traceback and *if* it happens again you'll have the traceback.

Answer (score 1):

You could also setup the [logging module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) to print out your errors to a file for later inspection

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
try:
    # your code ...
except:
    import traceback
    tb = traceback.format_exc()
    print tb
```

Comment: Interesting to import the library in n the except.   But I hoped to print the last traceback, not the next one. Unfortunately, that seems impossible.

Comment: The OP already links to the `traceback` library in their question.